# Is it a bug in Limit?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, wolfram-alpha-queries

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 10.0.0 and reintroduced in 11.2**

---

Mathematica 9 on Windows and WolframAlpha says

```
Limit[Sin[Sqrt[x+1]]-Sin[Sqrt[x]],x->Infinity]
```

is Interval[{-2,2}].
But actually the limit is 0.

```
Limit[TrigFactor[Sin[Sqrt[x+1]]-Sin[Sqrt[x]]],x->Infinity]
```

gives 0 correctly.

Comment: Your second limit should read `Limit[TrigFactor[Sin[Sqrt[x + 1]] - Sin[Sqrt[x]]], x -> Infinity]`. With Mma version 10.2 on a Mac, both limits evaluate to zero. What version and system are you using?

Comment: @BobHanlon I can repro the OP results in Mma v9

Comment: @BobHanlon Mma 9 on windows.And W|A says -2 to 2 similarly.

Comment: This is apparently a v9 bug. Version 8.04, 10.0.2, 10.1 and 10.2 all give 0.

Comment: My version 9 is 9.01. I don't have earlier releases of 10.0 than 10.0.2. Anyone with earlier releases please check for more accurate bug introduction and fix numbers.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries 10.0.0 gives 0; updated Q.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 10.0.0

Comment: @Lou I'd rather leave this for V9 users.

Comment: No need to close; the CW answer should be sufficient if it gets at least one upvote, and the standard header is already in place.

Comment: In v11.2, first limit has gone back to `Interval[{-2, 2}]`

Comment: Sorry about that. 11.3 should get it right again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Case closed but the topic should be left here for future visitors who use V9.

So:

> Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 10.0.0

Comment: In the spirit of community and user-oriented, Thanks!

Comment: @Lou Thanks comrade :)